# MLlib and pyspark features

Tags: python, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I would like to use **areaUnderROC** from **MLlib** in **Apache Spark**. I am currently running Spark 1.1.0 and this function is not available in pyspark but is available in scala.

Is there a feature tracker that tracks the advancement of porting Scala apis to Python apis?

I have tried to search in the official jira but I could not find any ticket number corresponding to this.

Answer (score 2):

[`pyspark.mllib.evaluation.BinaryClassificationMetrics.areaUnderROC`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.mllib.html#module-pyspark.mllib.evaluation) has been introduced in Spark 1.4.0:

```
from pyspark.mllib.evaluation import BinaryClassificationMetrics

scoreAndLabels = ...
BinaryClassificationMetrics(scoreAndLabels).areaUnderROC
```